# not getting updated fields using django signals

Tags: django, django-signals

I am trying to fetch the updated fields using django signals.when i update the model using update view and call the post_save i get the update_fields as None in the kwargs.
How to get the updated fields using django signals ??

signals.py

```
from .models import Department
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=Department)
def department_history(sender, created, **kwargs):
 update = kwargs['update_fields']
```

views.py

```
class DepartmentEditView(LoginRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin,PermissionRequiredMixin, UpdateView):

model = Department
form_class = DepartmentForm
success_url = reverse_lazy('departments:departments')
success_message ="%(department_name)s was Updated Sucessfully "
template_name_suffix = '_update'
permission_required = ('departments.change_department',)
```

Comment: try change to `def department_history(sender, instance=Department(), created, update_fields, **kwargs):` and check `update_fields` again

Comment: i still get None

Comment: try this:  `def department_history(sender, instance, created, **kwargs): if created:  update = kwargs['update_fields']
`

Comment: during update the created is False only in create it is True            refer:- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/signals/#defining-and-sending-signals

Answer (score 0):

just update the code in views.py

```
def form_valid():
    obj=form.save(commit=False)
    obj.save(update_fields=['field_name'])
```

updated field name can be get using form.changed_data